# Laravel 5.5 Flash Message not working in blade file after redirect

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-5

I want to logout if user is_active == 0 on login function
My Code

LoginController.php

```
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    if($user->is_active == 0){
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect('/')->with(['errorMessage' => 'Your account is temporary blocked']);
    }
}
```

View Code:

```
@if(session('errorMessage'))
    <span class="alert alert-danger">
        {{session('errorMessage')}}
    </span>
@endif
```

Comment: Can you please share your '/' route? Maybe you are getting redirect because you are logged in?

Comment: dont check the session variable, when you passing keys with `with()`, you can use it as native variable like `$errorMessage`

Comment: @JMoura thanks it was my mistake i am redirecting to '/' route but then it is redirecting to default route '/login' after reach '/' route

Comment: @Sysix no, its a redirect, those variables are flashed to the session

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was redirected to the '/' instead of '/login'

Comment: that is exactly where you told it to go to

Comment: yes i want to redirect to the login page not to the home page